# Two Shape objects appear to be intersecting at the wrong location?

Tags: java, awt, collision-detection

I am trying to create a Shape with the centre of the ship being in the middle.

`one.x` and `one.z` is the X and Z positions of the ship. The ship size is about 100 on the X, and 50 on the Z.

```
Shape my = new Rectangle(
    (int) one.x - disToLeft, // upper-left corner X
    (int) one.z - disToTop,  // upper-left corner Y
    disToLeft + disToRight,  // width
    disToTop + disToBottom   // height
);
```

I'm then rotating the Shape, to of course be facing the correct way. This appears to work:

```
int rectWidth = (disToLeft + disToRight);
int rectHeight = (disToTop + disToBottom);
AffineTransform tr = new AffineTransform();

// rotating in central axis
tr.rotate(
    Math.toRadians(one.rotation),
    x + (disToLeft + disToRight) / 2,
    z + (disToTop + disToBottom) / 2
);
my = tr.createTransformedShape(my);
```

I am then doing the exact same thing with another Shape, and testing for intersection. This works.

However, it feels like the Shape is the incorrect dimensions. Or something. My ship is colliding very far out to one side (outside where it graphically exists), but through the other side, I can almost go right through the ship before any collision is detected!

Basically the Shapes are simply intersecting at the wrong location. And I cannot work out why. Either the shape, the location, or the rotation must be wrong.

```
int disToLeft = 100;
int disToRight = 100;
int disToTop = 150;
int disToBottom = 100;
```

These are the distance from the centre to the left, right, top, and bottom sides.

I am using `Z` instead of `Y` because my game is in a 3D world and the sea level is pretty much the same (hence I don't need to worry about Y axis collision!).

**Update:**
After doing a lot of testing, I have discovered that the top of the rectangle is in the middle! I have done a lot of messing around, but without being able to graphically see the squares, it's been very hard to test.
This means that the box is on the side of the ship, like this:
[image]

Obviously when the ship on the left rotates to what it's like in this picture, a collision is detected.
[image]

Comment: I've noticed some of the unused variables in my code or the bad practices. Please don't point them out, I'll fix them as soon as I have something that actually works.

Comment: You should isolate a test-case, and then step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth There's going to be something blatantly wrong that I just haven't noticed and someone else is.

Comment: its probably worth while drawing the box boundaries and offsets, making it toggle-able for testing purposes. The other thing is that you could replace the boat images with a solid colour to make sure the image's location is being represented accurately.

Comment: @doveyg "Image location is represented accurately"? What?

Comment: A test case (if an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is not possible) would indeed be helpful. Currently, one could only *guess* what *might* be wrong there...

Comment: @Joehot200, are they not images? the image may not be cropped properly, this would make the area appear bigger than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your rotation is wrong. From my understanding of math it should be

```
tr.rotate(Math.toRadians(one.rotation), x + (disToRight - disToLeft) /2, z + (disToBottom - disToTop) /2);
```

Note the signs and the order of the variables

Edit:

Let's take apart the formula:

Your Rectangle is defined like this:

```
x-coordinate (x): one.x-disToLeft
y-coordinate (y): one.z-disToTop
width: disToLeft+disToRight
height: disToTop+disToBottom
```

The centre of the Rectangle (where you are rotating) is therefore:

```
(x+width/2)
(y+height/2)
```

if you replace x, width, y and height with the declarations above you get

```
(one.x-disToLeft + (disToLeft+disToRight)/2)
(one.z-disToTop + (disToTop+disToBottom)/2)
```

This is already the point you need, but it can be simplyfied:

```
one.x-     disToLeft +   (disToLeft+disToRight)/2
 is equal to
one.x-(2*disToLeft/2)+(disToLeft/2)+(disToRight/2)
 is equal to
one.x-(distoLeft/2) + (disToRight/2)
 is equal to
one.x+(disToRight-disToLeft)/2
```

The other coordinate works exactly the same.

Comment: The minus between disToBottom-disToTop.

Comment: Hold on, why is it that minus the other one? I've just looked at that, and it makes no sense. Before, it was rotating on the centre of the ship. Now it rotates torwards the top left. Or at least, that's what my mathematical brain is telling me. Am I being completely stupid?

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit! It works now, and more to the point, I understand how it works. You deserve the +75 rep. :) (50 for the bounty, 15 for the accepted, 10 for the upvote - At least I can do those maths!)